# Running VSTO add-in from visual studio detaches debugger directly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I developed several Word add-ins with visual studio.

After working for over 2 years without any problems my dev machine is unable to load an add-in in Word (or Excel for that matter) and run Word (or Excel).

After several things I've tried, see below for details I'm still stuck in the same place. Word just directly stops causing VS to detach the debugger because VS obviously sees the process exit.

Some things to know:

- The event viewer does not show any errors
- I already added `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` with value 0 to the environment variables
- Word nor VS shows me a message what went wrong
- I already added `VSTO_LOGALERTS` with value 1 to the environment variables
- There is no logfile to be found somewhere in the [documented places](http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx)
- Loading Word directly loads the Add-in without any problem.
- If I attach the VS debugger to the Word process I'm able to set breakpoints and do normal debugging in the Add-in

What I've tried so far:

- Added the above mentioned environment variables to both user specific and system wide lists.
- Reboot my machine to make sure the environment variables where loaded properly
- Checked with RegEdit if the Add-In was correctly added to registry with a `LoadBehaviour` value of 3
- Repaired Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 (Update August)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 (Update August) (reboot in between)
- Made a complete new and empty Word Add-in to make sure there is nothing wrong => exact same problem
- Made a complete new and empty Excel Add-in => same problem with Excel.
- Used ProcMon to see if something is missing, but this shows too much information to clearly see what is happening. I do see there is no logfile being created.

So I'm completely in the dark why this is happening. It worked for at least 2 years on this machine. I can't find anyone with a similar problem on the net.

Hopefully somebody has a clue!